# Swift - UIView with constraint of zero height - error

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I have `UIView` with height constraint. I want to hide this view, so I set height constraint constant to 0.

I am setting constraint in code inside extended `UIView`:

```
_height = self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        _closeBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
        _closeBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        _closeBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: _centerLabel.heightAnchor),
        _closeBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: _closeBtn.heightAnchor),

        _centerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        _centerLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
        _centerLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: _closeBtn.trailingAnchor),
        _centerLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),

        _height
    ])
```

Now, If I change `_height.constant = 0`, I have got this error:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146a374c0 UIButton:0x147615b00'X'.width == UIButton:0x147615b00'X'.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146a37530 UIButton:0x147615b00'X'.height == UILabel:0x147615e80.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146a37450 V:|-(20)-[UILabel:0x147615e80]   (active, names: '|':InternetConnectionInfoView:0x14742f600 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146a373e0 UILabel:0x147615e80.bottom == InternetConnectionInfoView:0x14742f600.bottom - 5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146a37680 InternetConnectionInfoView:0x14742f600.height == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146a374c0 UIButton:0x147615b00'X'.width == UIButton:0x147615b00'X'.height   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146a37530 UIButton:0x147615b00'X'.height == UILabel:0x147615e80.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146a37450 V:|-(20)-[UILabel:0x147615e80]   (active, names: '|':InternetConnectionInfoView:0x14742f600 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146a373e0 UILabel:0x147615e80.bottom == InternetConnectionInfoView:0x14742f600.bottom - 5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146a37680 InternetConnectionInfoView:0x14742f600.height == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146a373e0 UILabel:0x147615e80.bottom == InternetConnectionInfoView:0x14742f600.bottom - 5   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I suspect, that this comes from top and bottom anchor being set to constant values. I have tried to use `greaterThanOrEual` / `lessThanOrEqual`, but it destroys the layout.

How to solve this (eg. hiding UIView)? I cannot set isHidden, because other UIViews are anchored to the bottom of this view and they need to move upon hiding.

Comment: I found that making a `UIView` height to 0 also means you need to set it's subviews `isHidden` to true. Have you tried that? EDIT: I have a view that is a sliding menu of sliders. It animates well - just set `isHidden` for the subviews, then set the height of the main view to 0, then animate it.

Comment: @dfd Not working, same error

Comment: Change the priority of one of the constraints to 999.

Comment: @Sulthan of which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a constraint conflict, consider reducing the constraint priority can help you fix this issue.

```
let closeBtnTopAnchor = _closeBtn.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.topAnchor)
let closeBtnTopAnchorWithLowPriority = _closeBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10)
closeBtnTopAnchorWithLowPriority.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh

let centerLabelTopAnchor = _centerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.topAnchor)
let centerLabelTopAnchorWithLowPriority = _centerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10)
centerLabelTopAnchorWithLowPriority.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh

let centerLabelBottomAnchor = _centerLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.bottomAnchor)
let centerLabelBottomAnchorWithLowPriority = _centerLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
centerLabelBottomAnchorWithLowPriority.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

   _closeBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
   closeBtnTopAnchor,
   closeBtnTopAnchorWithLowPriority,

   _closeBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: _centerLabel.heightAnchor),
   _closeBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: _closeBtn.heightAnchor),

   centerLabelTopAnchor,
   centerLabelTopAnchorWithLowPriority,
   centerLabelBottomAnchor,
   centerLabelBottomAnchorWithLowPriority,
   _centerLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: _closeBtn.trailingAnchor),
   _centerLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),

   _height
   ])
```

Answer (score 0):

If hiding the UIView is enough for you, how about setting its `alpha` to 0 ?

Comment: It wont move views thats anchors depend on height of hideable view.

Comment: Oh I see, then is it a case that you can use those views within a `UIStackView` ? I've run into such a case only once and using it solved my problem.

Comment: If not, adjusting those dependent constraints according to the height when you set it to 0 should work, though I assume it could be a bad practice.